# JS Playlist Function

Tags: javascript, playlist

I'm Using this code to make a playlist where will play videos from youtube but i cant make there highlight corrent track becouse its in youtube playlist how i will edit code to be possible this function ?

```
function addToplaylist(title)
{
    window.title= title;
    $("#video").html('<img src="/img/24.gif">');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/includes/ajax.php',
        data: {title: title},
        success: function(result) {
            var playlist = $.cookie('playlist');

            if (playlist!=null && playlist!="") {
                $.cookie("playlist", playlist+','+result, { expires: 500, path: '/' });
                var playlistt = $.cookie('playlistt');
                var cookie = playlistt+','+window.title;
                $.cookie("playlistt", cookie, { expires: 500, path: '/' });
                $("#video").html('<div style="left:5px;position:relative;width:99%;height:29px;overflow:hidden;float:left;"><div style="position:absolute;top:-273px;left:-3px"><iframe width="690" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +result+ '/?autoplay=1&playlist=' +playlist+'&rel=0"></iframe></div>');
            } else {
                $.cookie("playlist", result, { expires: 500, path: '/' });
                var playlistt = $.cookie('playlistt');
                $.cookie("playlistt", window.title, { expires: 500, path: '/' });
                var cookie = window.title;
                $("#video").html('<div style="left:5px;position:relative;width:99%;height:29px;overflow:hidden;float:left;"><div style="position:absolute;top:-273px;left:-3px"><iframe width="690" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +result+ '/?autoplay=1&rel=0"></iframe></div>');
           }

            var playlistts=cookie.split(",");
            document.getElementById("player").style.display = 'block';

            $("#close").html('<a class="icon-remove" title="Close Player"></a>');
            $("#drop").html('<div class="btn-group plinfo"><div class="btn btn-inverse">'+playlistts.length+' Tracks In Playlist</div><div onclick="dropPlaylist()" class="btn btn-inverse" title="Cleanup Playlist">Cleanup Playlist</div></div>');
            $("#drag").html('<a class="icon-move" style="cursor:move;" title="Drag Player"></a>');

            var each = playlistts.join('</span><li><img class="plimg" onload="this.src = \'/includes/image.php?\'+$(this).next(\'span.titletrack\').text()" src="/img/cover.png"><span  onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">');
             $("#playlist").html('<li><img src="/img/cover.png"><span  onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">' + each);

            var divCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("playlist");
            for (var i = 0; i < divCollection[0].childElementCount; i++) {
                if (divCollection[0].children[i].textContent == window.title) {
                findMeText = divCollection[0].children[i];
                window.setTimeout(function() { findMeText.style.background = '#aaa'; }, 0);
                window.setTimeout(function() { findMeText.style.background = '#000'; }, 3000);
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You need to use the Youtube javascript API. It won't be enough to "change" your code. Investigate the API, try to implement it, then ask questions here if you have specific issues with it. https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: and how to write function thats will be make call or event after ending video before going to netx video

Comment: You get the entire playlist with `player.getPlaylist()`. You get the current "index" into that playlist with `player.getPlaylistIndex()`. You could either poll it on an interval, or subscribe to the `stateChange` event and wait until you get states that aren't playing/paused/buffering and do it *then*.